What is the meaning of the following terms in the hadith?
The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said,

“Every one of you is a shepherd and is responsible for his flock. The leader of people is a guardian and is responsible for his subjects. A man is the guardian of his family and he is responsible for them. A woman is the guardian of her husband’s home and his children and she is responsible for them. The servant of a man is a guardian of the property of his master and he is responsible for it. No doubt, every one of you is a shepherd and is responsible for his flock.”
Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 7138, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 1829

From this hadith please elaborate on the difference between role of man and a woman, what is meant by being a "guardian" and by responsibility of "husband's home"?
Please provide the source too for your answer.

Use the block quote feature  whenever you cite. For more help checkout : https://islam.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Please elaborate anyone, from any books like Imam Nawai's or Fath Al Bari of Ibn Hajar or any acceptable book. I don't know Arabic that's why can't refer to Fath Al Bari or majority of interpretation of early times that are not translated.
